# Is the distance between photons the wavelength of light?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, atomic-physics, wavelength

I have a question that may be naive for you, but I would like you to answer it

The  question

Is the distance between photons the wavelength of light?

Comment: A prior question: Are photons evident in light as it travels, or only when light interacts with matter?

Comment: So I'm querying whether "the distance between photons" can be given any meaning. [Perhaps that's why your question was closed.] But if it can, it wouldn't in general equal the wavelength of the light. For example if we increased the intensity of the light, presumably the photons would be crowded closer together, yet we could keep the wavelength the same.

Comment: The intensity of the light has nothing to do with the proximity or spacing of the photons, and I think you never understood the point of the question. Increasing the flux of photons is not the same as increasing the radiation as you think.

Philip Wood

Comment: I bow to your superior knowledge and understanding.

Comment: I take it that you don't much like *this* answer to a similar question... "The average distance between photons can be estimated in the following conceptual way.
First, calculate the energy density of the blackbody radiation field.
Then divide by the average energy of a photon."

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much. I am very grateful to you  
Philip Wood